# Gnuplot: Meaning of the second column of smooth kdensity

Tags: statistics, gnuplot, kernel-density

I am new to gnuplot. I am also new to the Kernel Density Resampling using a Gaussian supported by gnuplot using “smooth kdensity”. I played with the gnuplot demo script provided below. I am trying to understand what the meaning of the second column is of $kdensity1. If I print $kdensity1 I get these values:

(...)
140.76  13.1663  13.1663  i
146.032  12.5092  12.5092  i
151.304  11.6501  11.6501  i
156.575  10.6298  10.6298  i
161.847  9.5347  9.5347  i
167.119  8.48325  8.48325  i
172.391  7.56657  7.56657  i
177.662  6.80631  6.80631  i
(...)

The first column seems to be the computed Gaussian kernel over the sample values defined by the second column of $viol1 provided by the randomized expression.  But I am trying to understand how the second column of $kdensity1 is computed since it defines the “density” or the spread of the violin plot. And it seems the 20.0 constant from the $2/20.0 computing is assumed. But this value must surely be different given another sample set that has a different range. Thus, how is column 2 of $kdensity1 computed (or what is its relationship) and how can I find the constant (20) for computing the spreading?

```
nsamp = 3000 
set print $viol1
do for [i=1:nsamp] {
    y = (i%4 == 0) ? 300. +  70.*invnorm(rand(0)) \
      : (i%4 == 1) ? 400. +  10.*invnorm(rand(0)) \
      :              120. +  40.*invnorm(rand(0))
    print sprintf(" 35.0 %8.5g", y)
}
unset print

set title "kdensity mirrored sideways to give a violin plot"

set table $kdensity1
plot $viol1 using 2:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 10. with filledcurves above y lt 9 title 'B'
unset table

set border 2
unset margins
unset xtics
set ytics nomirror rangelimited

set xrange [-1:5]
plot  $kdensity1 using (3 + $2/20.):1 with filledcurve x=3 lt 9 notitle, '' using (3 - $2/20.):1 with filledcurve x=3 lt 9 notitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to [this violin plot demo](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/violinplot.html). Check on Wikipedia [Kernel_(statistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) and from gnuplot `help kdensity`:

> The **smooth kdensity** option generates and plots a kernel density estimate using Gaussian kernels for the distribution from which a set of values was drawn. Values are taken from the first data column, optional weights are taken from the second column. A Gaussian is placed at the location of each point and the sum of all these Gaussians is plotted as a function. To obtain a normalized histogram, each weight should be 1/number-of-points. 
> ...

and have a look at the further minimized example.

- the input data `$Data` requires only one column of data
- when plotting to a table with option `smooth kdensity` the part `(1)` is the weight of that datapoint, here constant value of `1` (because of the parentheses). As `help kdensity` suggests, you can use `(1/N)` instead, where `N` is the number of points to get a normalized violin plot.
- I don't understand why the original example is using `with filledcurves above y lt 9 title 'B'` for plotting it to a table. This generates a unnecessary 3rd column which is identical to the 2nd column.

As I understand, for each datapoint there will be a Gaussian kernel with a given width and the area 1. And you sum up all Gaussians which will give you the shape of the curve in the second column of `$kdensity`.

Concerning `$2/20.`, I guess, this factor `20.` in the example is just a scaling factor that the two violin plots do not collide in the graph.

In order to find out a reasonable scaling factor automatically, you could do a `stats` to get the maximum of the second column of the datablock `$kdensity`.
If you want to compare several violin plots you should take the maximum of all maxima as scaling factor.

And the `3 +`  and `3 -`  in the plot command is simply an x-offset where your violin plot is mirrored.

**Script:**

```
### violin plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1.0
2.0
4.0
1.0
2.0
2.0
EOD

N = |$Data|
set table $kdensity
    plot $Data u 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.2
unset table

stats [*:*][*:*] $kdensity u 2
print STATS_max, STATS_min

set key noautotitle
set xrange[1:5]
set yrange[0:5]

plot $kdensity u (3 + $2/STATS_max):1 w filledcurve x=3 lt 9, \
            '' u (3 - $2/STATS_max):1 w filledcurve x=3 lt 9
### end of script
```

Actually, you could shorten the plot command to a single line:

```
plot for [i=-1:1:2] $kdensity u (3 + i*$2/STATS_max):1 w filledcurve x=3 lt 9
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right. Using your explanation with the information provided at this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/kernel-density-estimation-explained-step-by-step-7cc5b5bc4517 I could understand the second column. If I use a $Data with a single value 1, I can compute the second value, the "impulse" response of the Gaussian kernel. The computed values match the second column of $kdensity.

Comment: A second comment. It just hit me. The explanation given for the kernel density use the terminology of “Mathematic Statistic”. But from an Electrical Engineering terminology the kernel density function is the transfer resampling function of a low pass filter. The resampling transfer function is normalized to 1 to provide a gain of 1 to the filtering process. Thus, the second column is the output of the filtering of the samples done by convoluting the input samples with the low pass transfer resampling function. The violon plot rotates the filtered input samples by 90 degrees and mirrors it.